# Getting issues while passing collection object to oracle Stored procedure

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oracle11g

As part of my project requirement I need to pass Collection of objects (List of objects) to oracle stored procedure. And Once I receive the collection object In stored procedure I will do some DB operation using the data. I am getting some issue in java code while setting the argument for stored procedure.

From database side I have created custom type.

```
create or replace type ESLSolveRequests as Object(latitude Number(38,10),longitude Number(38,10),isExist char(1),rec_id Number,route_cost Number,route_length Number,route_impedance Number);
create or replace type ESLSolveList as table of ESLSolveRequests;
```

Below are Package and stored procedure

```
create or replace package PKG_ESL_NSX_Record_Check as 

procedure proc_Check_RecordExistance(MAP_IN IN ESLSolveList,MAP_OUT OUT ESLSolveList);

end PKG_ESL_NSX_Record_Check;
create or replace package body PKG_ESL_NSX_Record_Check
as 

procedure proc_Check_RecordExistance(MAP_IN IN ESLSolveList,MAP_OUT OUT ESLSolveList)

is

begin

null;

end proc_Check_RecordExistance;
end PKG_ESL_NSX_Record_Check;
```

Below is java code ,my List List eslSolveRequest is populated with objects, below is my java code

```
@Repository
public class EslNsxCheckDao extends DatabaseConnection {

    private StructDescriptor strDescriptor = null;
    private ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = null;
    private OracleCallableStatement cStmt = null;
    private ARRAY p_message_list = null;
    Connection con = null;

    public void checkWithNSXDb(List<ESLSolveRequest> eslSolveRequest){

        oracle.sql.ARRAY array =null;
        try{
        Connection con=getJdbcConnection();
        this.arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ESLSolveList", con);
        this.strDescriptor=StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("ESLSolveRequests",con);
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
        try {
            Object[] param_array=eslSolveRequest.toArray();
            p_message_list = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(this.arrayDescriptor, con, param_array);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            this.cStmt =(OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("{call PKG_ESL_NSX_Record_Check.proc_Check_RecordExistance(:1,:2)}");         
            this.cStmt.setArray(1, p_message_list);
            this.cStmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.ARRAY,"ESLSolveList");
            this.cStmt.execute();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I am getting below error

```
**java.sql.SQLException: Missing descriptor**
        at oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection.assertNotNull(DatumWithConnection.java:103)
        at oracle.sql.ARRAY.<init>(ARRAY.java:117)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.DAO.EslNsxCheckDao.checkWithNSXDb(EslNsxCheckDao.java:37)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.DAO.EslNsxCheckDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b62b799d.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.DAO.EslNsxCheckDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c531bd5.checkWithNSXDb(<generated>)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.Batch.Processor.process(Processor.java:28)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.Batch.Processor.process(Processor.java:12)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.Events.ScheduledEvents.trigger(ScheduledEvents.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
        at** oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setARRAYInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6405)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setArrayInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6362)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setArray(OracleCallableStatement.java:5682)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setArray(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:121)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.DAO.EslNsxCheckDao.checkWithNSXDb(EslNsxCheckDao.java:45)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.DAO.EslNsxCheckDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b62b799d.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.DAO.EslNsxCheckDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c531bd5.checkWithNSXDb(<generated>)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.Batch.Processor.process(Processor.java:28)
        at com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.Batch.Processor.process(Processor.java:12)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
```

Comment: The types owner is the same user used on application datasource? If not, the datasource user has enough permissions to handle this types?

Comment: Yes user is same with permissions, I have used same user for creating types from DB side and to connect through application.

Comment: The first catch block is empty. May be an error ocurred when try to create descriptors. it's could be a cause for the Missing descriptor error (descriptor would be null) Add code to empty catch block to log any exception

Comment: You are correct , Descriptor is null and the error is java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: NTSLV_BLK_O.ESLSolveList.

Comment: Its because of lowercase, changed to upper case ESLSOLVELIST andworked for me. Now I got different issue @ Object[] param_array=eslSolveRequest.toArray();
   p_message_list = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(this.arrayDescriptor, con, eslSolveRequest);

Exception I got : java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: [com.comcast.BulkSolveRecordProcess.Pojo.ESLSolveRequest@d55865,...]

It seems the Java List/Object[] not converting  to sql ARRAY type.

Comment: Could be that the error were because the out parameter is not an object? Out parameteres are used to store procedures results. Create a p_out_list like p_message_list, use it as a out parameter and try again.